# JQuery button click auto click next button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make it so my JQuery auto clicks the next button if the button is pressed.
On the internet I found that should be like this (look at JQuery section).
But for some reason it doesn't work.

Do they have to be in the same `<div>` in order to work like that?

What I have tried:
JQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sobmit").bind("click", (function () { 
      }));
      $("#submit").bind("click", (function () {
        $("#sobmit").trigger("click");  
      }));
    });
</script>
```

Button 1 in a form

html:

```
<input type="submit" id="sobmit" name="sobmit" value="sobmit" placeholder="sobmit" />
```

Button 2 in a form

html:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div>
```

Comment: `bind`??? You need to get some more up-to-date internet sources!   That was superseded in 2011.

Comment: change `$("#sobmit").trigger("click");` to `$("#sobmit")[0].click()` if you want to submit a form from the button click.   Also note your submit/sobmit are around the wrong way from your description (your code is: click 2nd button to fire 1st button)

Comment: so basically what the first buttons(sobmit) does is selecting a certain eanNr within the database. The second button puts it into the cart/inventory/listed. (it for a e-commerce backup)

Comment: And bind as i only could find old posts on websites about this subject and they all answered that it should be like this (some of them were even 8 years ago i believe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){ 
  $("#sobmit").trigger("click");
  console.log("#sobmit button get clicked by trigger");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Button 1 <input type="submit" id="sobmit" name="sobmit" value="sobmit" placeholder="sobmit" />
<br><br>
Button 2 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the try. Sadly enough it didn't work. But i am thinking about remake the entire project